# UITableViewCell left side color

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios4

I would like to set a color to the most left of my UITableViewCell, BUT I want it to fall withing the bounds of the cell. 
Because I use a UITableViewStyleGrouped UITableView I would like the color to have a round corner for the first and last cell. How can I do this?

I currently have the color in the table, but thats it. This is my code:

```
UIView *theView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, cell.frame.size.height)];
[theView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];

[cell.contentView addSubview:theView];

[[cell textLabel] setText:@"Some row"];
```

This is the result:
[image]

Best regards,
Paul Peelen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest and easiest way is to use images for the first and last cells.

There is a bit more sophisticated way - drawing with a help of [Core Graphics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreGraphics/Reference/CoreGraphics_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007127)

**EDIT:** your case is just a [rectangle](http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/2009/08/how-to-draw-shapes-with-core-graphics/) plus a quoter of ellipse (or just a [pie slice](http://rajeev.name/2009/01/18/drawing-pie-charts-using-iphone-sdk/)).

Answer (score 1):

I solved it in the end using "CoreGraphics" as NR4TR suggested.

I created a new UIView and rewrote the drawRect function.

This is the result code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    float radius = 10.0f;

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();   
    rect = CGRectInset(rect, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, CGRectGetMinX(rect) + radius, CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));


    if (bottom)
    {
        CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMinX(rect) + radius, CGRectGetMaxY(rect) - radius, radius, M_PI / 2, M_PI, 0);
    }
    else {  
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));
    }

    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));

    if (top)
    {
        CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMinX(rect) + radius, CGRectGetMinY(rect) + radius, radius, M_PI, 3 * M_PI / 2, 0);
    }
    else {
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    }

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, theColor.CGColor);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
}
```

Comment: You'd better add your solution to your answer with the label _Solution_ than posting an answer to your own question. Just a matter of stackoverflow :)